# How to check if AWS AMI support cloud-init?

Tags: amazon-ec2, user-data, cloud-init, ec2-ami

In AWS Console when launching an instance with any image I get "user data" field to fill in optionally to be later executed by cloud-init. However, not all images support cloud-init. How do I check if an AWS image supports cloud-init or not? I can see the "user data" field for any image I randomly choose.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuqer.png)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?